# Finding Uppercase Letters including small brackets ()

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007, word-2003

I want to `Find` Four UPPERCASE/CAPITAL Letters which must include small brackets `()`.

For example `(ABCD)`

Following code work fine with letters but it does not highlight brackets.

I think it is not finding brackets.

```
Sub FindUppercaseLetter()

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z])"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
End Sub
```

This is the case:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses have special meaning and need to be escaped wth a slash:

```
.Text = "\([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\)"
```

Comment: works fine. but i need to know at start you add slash before bracket `\(`but at end after `\)` ?

Comment: The syntax is *`slashX`* where `X` is the character to escape so `\(` escapes `(` and `\)` escapes `)`